# Eigenvalue problem in functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-integrals, integral-equations

How can I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of
\begin{align}
Ay(p):=\int_{0}^{\infty} k^2 \cos(pk)y(k)dk
\end{align}
$A$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.

Well actually, i came across this in solving a non-linear Hammerstein equation where the non-linearity was in the reciprocal. I am solving it numerically by first determining the Gaussian process with sample paths defined by;
\begin{equation}
 y(k)=\sum_{i=1} ^{\infty}\frac{\alpha_i}{\sqrt{\rho_i}}u_i(k),\quad\quad y\quad\epsilon \quad L^2 
\end{equation}
$L^2$ is Hilbert space of functions $y$ on $[0,\Lambda]$ with the usual norm.

Also $\alpha_i$ is a sequence of random variable with mean 0 and variance 1. Here $\rho_i$ and $u_i(k)$ are eigenvalue and eigenvectors of the co-variance function defined earlier. The upper limit of the operator equation could be taken to be some cutoff $\Lambda$. Remember, the co-variance or kernel$(k^2 cos(pk))$  is non-degenerate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the space on which you define $A$, but if we take for example $C^{\infty}\left([0,\infty[\right)$, we can choose a basis of functions and see if we can find coefficients such that a linear combination of basis functions is an eigenfunction. This is actually really similar to the finite dimensional case.

Concretely, you could use the Fourier basis $\{e^{2\pi i lx} | l \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, in which all functions of $C^{\infty}\left([0,\infty[\right)$ can be written down as 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k e^{2\pi i kx}.
$$
Plugging this into the equation (and assuming everything converges) leads to equations for the coefficients that are solvable.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Hrodelbert. $A$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt Operator, i rephrased the question again. Will look forward to your response.

Comment: @Immo Ali. How do you know that it is Hilbert-Schmidt? To compute its Hilbert-Schmidt norm you need an orthonormal basis of your function space. This basis could be used conform the example I gave above to determine equations that are solvable.

Comment: So if i have a co-variance function $\rho(p,k)$ such that

Comment: @Hrodelbert.So if i have a co-variance function $\rho (p,k)$ such that $\int_0 ^{\Lambda}\int_0 ^{\Lambda}\rho (p,k)^2 dp dk < \infty $ and is positive definite, then it defines the positive definite Hilbert-Schmidt operator A as stated earlier. Also $L^2$ is a Hilbert space of functions y on $[0,\Lambda]$ with norm $(y,y)^{1/2}=\lbrace[\int_0 ^{\Lamda}y^2(k) dk\rbrace]^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Immo Ali Then I stand by my original answer: the space $L_2([0,\Lambda])$ is spanned by the Fourier basis of exponentials with period $\Lambda$, so you can use the action of $A$ on these functions to determine eigenfunctions.

Comment: What does period of $\Lambda$ means?

Comment: That the functions of the basis have period $\Lambda$ means that they $f(x) = f(x+\Lambda)$ for all $x$, but in our case this is unimportant.